# How to do a double request?

Tags: node.js

How can I do a double request in Nodejs?

```js
function script() {
  request(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json`, function
  (error, res, body) {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.parse(body))
    }
  })

}
```

This is my code and I want to make another request to find the title. Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to make the request in the callback function of the first request.

```
function script() {
  request('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json', function (error, res, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.parse(body));
      var titleUrl = '';
      request(titleUrl, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This is fine for simple applications, but it will get unwieldy and ugly pretty quickly. I suggest [learning the Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You'll need a different request library than `request` since it does not natively support Promises. Based on experience, [I suggest using `got` if you can](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

```
function script() {
  got('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
      let titleUrl = "";
      return got(titleUrl)
    })    
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```